# Доступ к массиву в main()

Tags: visual-c++, c++

Вопрос следующий, что должна возвращать целочисленная функция, в которой задаётся динамический массив, чтобы после её вызова этот массив был доступен в main?
у меня был такой вариант:

```
int* mass(int& a, int& b);  
int main(int argc, char** argv) {  
    int n, i, min, *m;  
    cin >> n;   
    mass(i, n);   
    min=*m[0];  
    system("pause");  
    return 0;  
}  
int* mass(int& a, int& b){   
    int *m = new int[b];  
    for (a=0;a<b;a++)  
        cin>>m[a];  
    return m;  
}
```

но так не прокатывает, полагаю, что m надо как-то глобально определить, не понимаю как именно это сделать, учитывая, что m - массив

Comment: @zhildemon, функция по идее должна возвращать указатель на первый элемент массива. А куда вы возвращаете результат работы mass? и указатель m на что у вас указывает? мб так сделать m = mass(i,n);

Comment: @zhildemon, чтобы оформить участок кода, выделите его, и нажмите на кнопочку фигурных скобок или Ctrl+k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все просто. Вы теряете тот-самый указатель, который возвращает вам функция mass.

```
int* mass(int& a, int& b);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int n, i, min, *m;
    cin >> n; 
    m = mass(i, n); // вот здесь
    min=*m[0];
    system("pause");

/* в таком коротком примере освобождать память не обязательно, но лучше сделать это хорошей привычкой */
    delete [] m;    
    return 0;
}
int* mass(int& a, int& b)
{ 
    int *m = new int[b];
    for (a=0;a<b;a++)
        cin>>m[a];
    return m;
}
```

Но вообще, чаще внешний указатель передают так называемым *выходным аргументом*. Это значит, что указатель передается по ссылке (указатель на указатель), значение которого меняется внутри функции, чтобы он указывал на новоиспеченный массив. Дело в том, что программист может забыть присвоить возвращаемое значение функции какой-либо переменной (как получилось у вас), а без аргумента необходимого типа программа просто не скомпилируется.
Кроме того, если вы не собираетесь менять значение аргументов, то их вполне можно передавать по значению. Может получиться так:

```
void mass(int b, int **arr);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int n, min, *m;
    cin >> n; 
    mass(n, &m); // вот здесь снова другой вызов
    min=*m[0];
    system("pause");

    delete [] m;    
    return 0;
}
void mass(int b, int **arr)
{ 
    *arr = new int[b];
    for (int i=0;i<b;i++)
        cin>>*arr[i];
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое, в будущем буду учитывать, я сделал несколько иначе    
int* mass(int b){  
 int *m = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * b);  
 for (int a = 0; a < b; a++)  
 cin >> m[a];  
 return m;  
}

Comment: P.S. какими символами задаётся блок кода? на странице с описанием были <pre><code>...</code></pre>, но очевидно, что не сработало)

Comment: @zhildemon, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: @Free_ze, ух ты!)) ещё раз спасибо, Вам)

Comment: @zhildemon, а код в комментариях делаем так:

вводим пустую строку, а на

    следуещей и 
    далее 4 пробела в начале
       или еще несколько
    и завершаем 

пустой строкой

Comment: @Free_ze, Попробовал скомпилировать ваш код, хочу разобраться в этом методе задания.Выдаёт ошибку в строке
  
    min=*m[0];    
  
компилятор VS говорит, что это недопустимое косвенное обращение, в Dev-C++ "invlid type argument of unary '*'(have 'int')", не до конца понимаю, что он хочет

Comment: @zhildemon скобочки вокруг звездочки, пардон =)

    min=(*m)[0];

Во всех подобных случаях. Ибо приоритет [] выше, чем *

Comment: А лучше без всяких изысков писать

    min = m[0];

Comment: @zhildemon
Не вчитался. Имел в виду следующее внутри mass:

    cin>>(*arr)[i];